# Iterator prints two values, one is text and other is unfortunately a pointer

Tags: c++

the following code shows four messages, the first two are normal, the other two passes through an iterator, but the second one doesn't show the right value, but prints the pointer instead of the value, but the code is almost the same for the two variables.

The code is big, the IMPORTANT part is inside main and show_message, the problem is that **anm->getName()** works and **anm->getParent()->getName()** doesn't

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Node;
class CustomObject;

class CustomObject
{
    public:
    std::string name;
    Node* parent;
    CustomObject(std::string n_name);
    std::string getName();
    void setParent(Node* pparent);
    Node* getParent();
};

CustomObject::CustomObject(std::string n_name)
{
    name = n_name;
}

std::string CustomObject::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void CustomObject::setParent(Node* pparent)
{
    parent = pparent;
}

Node* CustomObject::getParent()
{
    return parent;
}

class Node
{
public:
    std::string name;
    Node* parent;
    std::vector<Node> childs;
    Node(std::string n_name);
    void attach(Node* nd);
    void attach(CustomObject* anm);
    std::string getName();
    void setParent(Node* pparent);
    Node* getParent();
    std::vector<CustomObject> mCustomObjects;
};

Node::Node(std::string n_name)
{
    name = n_name;
}

std::string Node::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Node::setParent(Node* pparent)
{
    parent = pparent;
}

Node* Node::getParent()
{
    return parent;
}

void Node::attach(Node* nd)
{
    childs.push_back(*nd);
    nd->setParent(this);
}

void Node::attach(CustomObject* anm)
{
    mCustomObjects.push_back(*anm);
    anm->setParent(this);
}

class Game
{
    std::string name;
public:

    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    std::vector<CustomObject> mCustomObjects;
    Game(std::string nm);
};

Game::Game(std::string nm)
{
    name = nm;
}

void show_message(CustomObject* anm)
{
    MessageBox( NULL, anm->getName().c_str(),"Message", 0);
    MessageBox( NULL, anm->getParent()->getName().c_str(),"Message", 0);
}

int main()
{
    Game* mGame = new Game("MyGame");

    Node* mNode = new Node("MyNode");
    mGame->nodes.push_back(*mNode);
    CustomObject* mCustomObject = new CustomObject("Object1");
    mGame->mCustomObjects.push_back(*mCustomObject);
    mNode->attach(mCustomObject);

    show_message(mCustomObject);

    for (std::vector<CustomObject>::iterator itr = mGame->mCustomObjects.begin(); itr != mGame->mCustomObjects.end(); ++itr)
    {
        CustomObject* cObj;
        cObj = &(*itr);
        show_message(cObj);
    }
}
```

So, any idea what's wrong with this code?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'prints pointer'?

Comment: You are not using iterators correctly in your `for.`

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: One thing -- `Game* mGame = new Game("MyGame");`  C++ is not Java:  `Game mGame("MyGame");`  Plus your code will fail to compile with the default Visual Studio project settings (just to warn others trying this in Visual Studio).  You're using `char` based strings, but `MessageBox` and similar functions take `LPCTSTR` , not `const char*`.

Comment: @AndyG Just as an FYI if you use `[mcve]` in your comment it expands to [mcve]

Comment: It prints some strange characters, instead of "My Node"

Comment: @NathanOliver: Oh man that makes things so much easier

Comment: the code is big, the important part is the main and show_message, the problem is that anm->getName() works and anm->getParent()->getName() doesn't

Comment: `new Node` + push_back(*node)` is going to leak memory. Either keep pointers or keep copies.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah, you're right, but why the first one works and the second doesn't?

Comment: @PitterFisher *why the first one works and the second doesn't?* -- Because the first call to `show_message` doesn't use the `CustomObject` that you placed in the vector.  It uses the "real" object, which was set up properly.  The bottom line is that your vector has copies that are incorrect.  You should have inspected this in the debugger, as you will see parent objects for those entries are (or will more than likely be) bogus pointer values.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmm, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one problem, and basically is a symptom of your program:

```
void Node::attach(CustomObject* anm)
{
    mCustomObjects.push_back(*anm);
    anm->setParent(this);
}
```

You're calling this function, but take a look at it closely.  The first line dereferences the pointer and places a **copy** of the `CustomObject` in the vector.  The next line sets the parent, not of the copy that was placed in the vector, but the passed-in pointer.

So in the end, your vector winds up with copies that have bogus parent pointers.  You were lucky that you got to see any output at all.

[Crashing Example with Windows stuff removed](http://ideone.com/qMSPl6)

In addition to this, you have memory leaks in various places.  Your code doesn't  call `delete` at all.

The overall problem seems to be you are overusing pointers to the point that you're not sure whether to use value types or pointers.  I suggest you scrap all of this pointer-isms (or most of them), and use values.  Only if it is determined that yes, you must use a pointer should you use them.  Even if you use pointers, attempt to use a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you. this is just a fast code that i copied and edited from a large code, but i didn't noticed all those problems, is great to know that :)